# How to use a UITextField/UIWebView to access URL's but without including the http:// prefix in IOS5

Tags: http, url, ios5, uiwebview, uitextfield

I have a textField and a webView in a veiwController.

My problem is that when I enter a url that I want to go to, it won't load unless I include the http:// prefix.
I want my textField to act like the one in safari as in, it doesn't matter what I enter, it will find the website.

I want to be able to enter "stackoverflow.com" instead of "http://stackoverflow.com"

Is there some bit of code that this should be specified in or should this just work automatically?

If my code is needed let me know, but it seemed like this could possibly be answered without it.

Thanks!

Comment: Anybody have any idea? I'm so lost and have been searching for hours!